# Filtering 2nd field from a data set and then using uniq on the output

Tags: grep, sed, awk, uniq

I've got a dataset that goes like this:

```
AAAAA 11111 Data1
AAAAA 11111 Data2
AAAAA 11111 Data3
AAAAA 11112 Data4
AAAAA 11112 Data5
AAAAA 11112 Data6
AAAAA 11112 Data7
AAAAA 11113 Data8
AAAAA 11114 Data9
```

And so on.  I want to filter according to the 2nd field and then run a uniq to only pull the FIRST entry.  In this case, I want the output to be:

```
AAAAA 11111 Data1
AAAAA 11112 Data4
AAAAA 11113 Data8
AAAAA 11114 Data9
```

This seems like it would be pretty easy, but the method is just slipping me.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort` to do the work:

```
sort -k2,2 -u
```

`-k2,2` means operate only on the 2nd column, `-u` means unique.

Answer (score 0):

There's an idiomatic piece of awk to do it:

```
awk '!seen[$2]++' file
```

print out the line only the first time the value in the 2nd column has been seen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to sort it out

```
sort new.txt | rev | uniq -s 6 | rev
```

output of the file is as follows

[image]

Hope this helps